# CSS opacity ignored on Edge Mobile, but honored on other mobile and desktop browsers

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, opacity

The image is from another domain, but I can't find anything to indicate that that is the issue. I am going for an effect where it looks like an image is a watermark on parchment behind the text, and I can't directly alter the watermark image so it has to be done in CSS. The only browser that doesn't work is Microft's Edge on Mobile. Chrome mobile, and all desktop browsers I tried worked just fine.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Domestic Manners';
    src: url('domestic-manners.regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

* {
    font-family: "Domestic Manners";
    position: relative;
}

p {
    font-size:120%;
    text-indent: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    /* float:left; */
}

#main {
    margin:auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding:3em;
    background-image: url(/img/parchment-full.jpg);
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images img {
    height: 60;
    /* filter: grayscale(1) sepia(1) brightness(1.3); */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    /* To generate the dice images you can use the following js and then right click and save as the image */
    /* for (var i =10; i>=0; i--){place_dice("d10", i);} */
}

.creature {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index:-1;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    opacity:25%;
}
```

I removed the CSS that I'm 99% sure doesn't apply to make it easier to understand.
The HTML this is applying to is bellow. Note that the image tag is within the p.

```
<div id="main">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p><img class="creature" src="https://image-from-a-different-origin"/>
    Lorem Ipsum...
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by that Edge mobile doesn't have support for percentage opacity values. In [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Browser_compatibility), we can see that many browsers don't support percentage opacity values.

You could change

```
opacity:25%;
```

into

```
opacity: calc(25 / 100);
```

or

```
opacity: 0.25;
```

which have the same effect. Then it can work well on Edge mobile.